# Traceback in Needleman-Wunsch global alignment without storing pointer

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

My understanding is that while basically every discussion of dynamic programming I can find has one store the pointers as the matrix is populated, it is faster to instead to re-calculate the previous cells during the traceback step instead.

I have my dynamic programming algorithm to build the matrix correctly as far as I can tell, but I am confused on how to do the traceback calculations. I also have been told that it is necessary to recalculate the values (instead of just looking them up) but I don't see how that will come up with different numbers.

The version of SW I am implementing includes an option for gaps in both sequences to open up, so the recurrence relation for each matrix has three options. Below is the current version of my global alignment class. From my hand calculations I believe that score_align properly generates the matrix, but obviously traceback_col_seq does not work.

```
INF = 2147483647 #max size of int32
class global_aligner():
    def __init__(self, subst, open=10, extend=2, double=3):
        self.extend, self.open, self.double, self.subst = extend, open, double, subst
    def __call__(self, row_seq, col_seq):
        #add alphabet error checking?
        score_align(row_seq, col_seq)
        return traceback_col_seq()
    def init_array(self):
        self.M = zeros((self.maxI, self.maxJ), int)
        self.Ic = zeros((self.maxI, self.maxJ), int)
        self.Ir = zeros((self.maxI, self.maxJ), int)
        for i in xrange(self.maxI):
            self.M[i][0], self.Ir[i][0], self.Ic[i][0] = \
                    -INF, -INF, -(self.open+self.extend*i)
        for j in xrange(self.maxJ):
            self.M[0][j], self.Ic[0][j], self.Ir[0][j] = \
                    -INF, -INF, -(self.open+self.extend*j)
        self.M[0][0] = 0
        self.Ic[0][0] = -self.open
    def score_cell(self, i, j, chars):
        thisM = [self.Ic[i-1][j-1]+self.subst[chars], self.M[i-1][j-1]+\
                        self.subst[chars], self.Ir[i-1][j-1]+self.subst[chars]]
        thisC = [self.Ic[i][j-1]-self.extend, self.M[i][j-1]-self.open, \
                        self.Ir[i][j-1]-self.double]
        thisR = [self.M[i-1][j]-self.open, self.Ir[i-1][j]-self.extend, \
                        self.Ic[i-1][j]-self.double]
        return max(thisM), max(thisC), max(thisR)
    def score_align(self, row_seq, col_seq):
        self.row_seq, self.col_seq = list(row_seq), list(col_seq)
        self.maxI, self.maxJ = len(self.row_seq)+1, len(self.col_seq)+1
        self.init_array()
        for i in xrange(1, self.maxI):
            row_char = self.row_seq[i-1]
            for j in xrange(1, self.maxJ):
                chars = row_char+self.col_seq[j-1]
                self.M[i][j], self.Ic[i][j], self.Ir[i][j] = \
                        self.score_cell(i, j, chars)
    def traceback_col_seq(self):
        self.traceback = list()
        i, j = self.maxI-1, self.maxJ-1
        while i > 1 and j > 1:
            cell = [self.M[i][j], self.Ic[i][j], self.Ir[i][j]]
            cellMax = max(cell)
            chars = self.row_seq[i-1]+self.col_seq[j-1]
            if cell.index(cellMax) == 0: #M
                diag = [diagM, diagC, diagR] = self.score_cell(i-1, j-1, chars)
                diagMax = max(diag)
                if diag.index(diagMax) == 0: #match
                    self.traceback.append(self.col_seq[j-1])
                elif diag.index(diagMax) == 1: #insert column (open)
                    self.traceback.append('-')
                elif diag.index(diagMax) == 2: #insert row (open other)
                    self.traceback.append(self.col_seq[j-1].lower())
                i, j = i-1, j-1
            elif cell.index(cellMax) == 1: #Ic
                up = [upM, upC, upR] = self.score_cell(i-1, j, chars)
                upMax = max(up)
                if up.index(upMax) == 0: #match (close)
                    self.traceback.append(self.col_seq[j-1])
                elif up.index(upMax) == 1: #insert column (extend)
                    self.traceback.append('-')
                elif up.index(upMax) == 2: #insert row (double)
                    self.traceback.append('-')
                i -= 1
            elif cell.index(cellMax) == 2: #Ir
                left = [leftM, leftC, leftR] = self.score_cell(i, j-1, chars)
                leftMax = max(left)
                if left.index(leftMax) == 0: #match (close)
                    self.traceback.append(self.col_seq[j-1])
                elif left.index(leftMax) == 1: #insert column (double)
                    self.traceback.append('-')
                elif left.index(leftMax) == 2: #insert row (extend other)
                    self.traceback.append(self.col_seq[j-1].lower())
                j -= 1
        for j in xrange(0,j,-1):
            self.traceback.append(self.col_seq[j-1])
        for i in xrange(0,i, -1):
            self.traceback.append('-')
        return ''.join(self.traceback[::-1])    


test = global_aligner(blosumMatrix)
test.score_align('AA','AAA')
test.traceback_col_seq()
```

Comment: Just to clarify some terminology - Smith-Waterman is a local alignment algorithm, not a global alignment algorithm. Fortunately, it looks like your code is actually implementing something more akin to Needleman-Wunsch, which is a global alignment algorithm. But that might be confusing to some people. Also, are you sure that you mean linear programming? The more salient technique in sequence alignment algorithms is dynamic programming, and although I think that can be implemented with linear programming, the dynamic programming perspective seems more relevant to your question.

Comment: Sorry I have been working on this far too long. Yes, I am implementing Needleman-Wunsch here. And yes I meant dynamic programming.

Comment: Ah, okay, that makes more sense. I share your instinct that you shouldn't need to recalculate the scores - that would seem to defeat the entire point of dynamic programming. Could the person who told you this maybe have meant that you need to recalculate the scores you would have gotten if you came from each potential previous cell, to figure out which one matches? I also have a hard time seeing how this would be faster in the general case. Perhaps more memory efficient, though. Or maybe I'm just overlooking something.

Comment: Me too, it would seem that it would be faster to store the pointer. But also annoying to do in python. Regardless, it should still be possible to do the traceback by recalculating. I just can't seem to get it to work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem is that you aren't taking the matrix that you're currently in into account when generating the cells that you could potentially have come from. `cell = [self.M[i][j], self.Ic[i][j], self.Ir[i][j]]` is right for the first time through the while loop, but after that you can't just choose the matrix that has the highest score. Your options are constrained by where you're coming from. I'm having a bit of trouble following your code, but I think you're taking that into account in the if statements in the while loop. If that's the case, then I think changes along the lines of these should be sufficient:

```
 cell = [self.M[i][j], self.Ic[i][j], self.Ir[i][j]]
 cellIndex = cell.index(max(cell))
 while i > 1 and j > 1:
      chars = self.row_seq[i-1]+self.col_seq[j-1]
      if cellIndex == 0: #M
            diag = [diagM, diagC, diagR] = self.score_cell(i-1, j-1, chars)
            diagMax = max(diag)
            ...
            cellIndex = diagMax
            i, j = i-1, j-1
        elif cell.index(cellMax) == 1: #Ic
            up = [upM, upC, upR] = self.score_cell(i-1, j, chars)
            upMax = max(up)
            ...
            cellIndex = upMax
            i -= 1
        elif cell.index(cellMax) == 2: #Ir
            left = [leftM, leftC, leftR] = self.score_cell(i, j-1, chars)
            leftMax = max(left)
            ...
            cellIndex = leftMax
            j -= 1
```

Like I said, I'm not positive that I'm following your code correctly, but see if that helps.